# Getting Country / City data from google-app-engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, yaml

I am trying to access 2 headers on google app engine

```
X-AppEngine-Country
```

and

```
X-AppEngine-City
```

what i was trying to do is to useing $_REQUEST for example :

```
$_REQUEST["X-AppEngine-Country"]

$_REQUEST["X-AppEngine-City"]
```

and still not getting any data .

how can i access this headers ?

should i change values on the yaml file?

important : i am using php on google app engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `$_SERVER["HTTP_X_APPENGINE_COUNTRY"]` and `$_SERVER["HTTP_X_APPENGINE_CITY"]` instead.

See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/reference/request-response-headers#app_engine-specific_headers for additional fields.

The specific `$_SERVER` additions are listed here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/runtime#special_server_keys